# How to trigger an event when a customer don't open email using sitecore 9

Tags: exm, xconnect, marketing-automation

We send a mail when a customer fill up a simple form. We want to trigger an event if that customer don't open that mail in 7 days. How to achieve this goal in sitecore 9 using marketing automation?

Answer (score 1):

These steps should help you achieve your intentions:

1. Add custom submit action to your form which will save contact data (at least email) follow this [doc article](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/sitecore_forms/setting_up_and_configuring/walkthrough_creating_a_custom_submit_action_that_updates_contact_details).
2. Create goal and trigger it as another submit action on your form
3. Create another goal which you assign when somebody opens page from your link from email (probably you will have link in email)
4. Add goal from step 2 as initial event to your Marketing Automation and set rule when this goal is triggered start this marketing automation
5. Add another step in Marketing Automation which will listen 7 days to goal from step 3
6. If goal is triggered, assign your event as next step; If it's triggered you can assigned different functionality; There will be a yes/no branch in triggered goal condition

Answer (score 0):

You can make a marketing automation outcome like this
[image]

then trigger outcome like this

```
var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference("sitecoreextranet", email);
            var existingContact = client.Get<Sitecore.XConnect.Contact>(reference, new ContactExpandOptions(new string[] { DtgoProfileFacet.DefaultFacetKey }));
            if (existingContact != null)
            {
                var channelId = Guid.Parse("{52B75873-4CE0-4E98-B63A-B535739E6180}");
                    var interaction = new Interaction(existingContact, InteractionInitiator.Contact, channelId, "xConnectIntro Console App");
                    Guid outcomeId = Guid.Parse("{EB30DE38-B5C7-4256-B720-93145E9E1912}"); // ID of outcome item
                    var outcome = new Sitecore.XConnect.Outcome(outcomeId, DateTime.UtcNow, "USD", 100.00m);
                    interaction.Events.Add(outcome);
                    client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                    client.Submit();
                }
            }
```

This code above for "Yes path". End then you will add another action like send another email for "No path"
[image]